# How to detect when "Go" is pressed on Android Keyboard

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to detect when "Go" is pressed on the android Keyboard (the last key on the bottom right).
My code works in the emulator and on my Nexus 5, but doesn't on some other Android devices.
What am I doing wrong?

```
editTextMain.setImeActionLabel("Go", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
editTextMain.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
         if(i==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
         {
            Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, ActivityRisultati.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the `if` statement, and find out what value `i` has, and what value `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` has. If they're not the same, find out what the value of `i` means.

Comment: try KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // do your stuff here
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The keyboard was sending IME_ACTION_DONE instead of KEYCODE_ENTER.
I also added the test for the other cases (SEARCH Etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I have some code in my app which detects when any key which sends the `KEYCODE_ENTER` value is pressed.  It detects both the **Enter** and **Done** keys on a Motorola Droid 3 slide-out keyboard.  Here's my code:

```
private OnKeyListener enterKeyListener = new OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int k, KeyEvent e)
    {
        /*
         * "Enter" or "Done" key was pressed
         */

        if( (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && (e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) )
        {
            //
            // Do some stuff ...
            //

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Note the additional check for `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`.  You might need that on some devices in order to prevent the listener from firing as soon as the button is pressed, and repeatedly if the button is held down.  In my case, I only wanted it to take an action if the key had been pressed and then released.

Hope this helps.